# How do I redirect a link to a hosting space without a domian name?

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting, domain-name

I have a website which is already running but does not support php , so I bought another web hosting service . Now I want to redirect to the web hosting server through a link on my existing website .

I dont want to change the name server details of the existing website to the new host .

All i want to do is , redirect a link to the new hosting space and nothing else .

I hope am clear .

Comment: Just set 301 Redirect via .htaccess rules

Comment: where do I set it and to what ?

Answer (score 0):

Set 301 Redirect to your new hosting space URL or IP address by using `.htacess` rules

First, Create an empty text file using a text editor such as notepad, and save it as htaccess.txt
Now add this to that file:

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to new domain or hosting ip address
Redirect 301 / http://new-domain-example.com/
```

Finally upload this to your old server, and re-name it to .htaccess.

Comment: I dont think you understood my question , I have a link on my website which i want to redirect to the hosting space i bought .hosting space i bought does not have a domain name .

Comment: @CleanX Your question is not clear. You can't redirect to the hosting space without any link. Redirects are done via `headers` that follow HTTP protocol. You can only redirect the requests for example, if user comes to the old URL and you have set a redirect, his/her request is redirected and rather than the URL he requested, he's taken to the new URL for which redirect has been set.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a link on your old webpage that is a href, you can just use the ip address of your new server instead of a domain name in the href.